# What happens if a lambda in a step function makes a request to a server, using the callback pattern, then during processing the server restarts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, callback, aws-step-functions

What happens if a lambda in a step function makes a request to a server, using the callback pattern(sending a task token), then during processing the server restarts before sending any response to the step function?

EDIT: The server interaction is with the step function.

Comment: Is the server interaction with the step function or the lambda? What do you think will happen? The stepfunction cannot continue and will time out eventually.

Comment: With the step function via task tokens. The step function is waiting for a sendtasksuccess response. How long before the step function times out? Plus I have updated the question.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/sfn-stuck-execution.html *"By default, the Amazon States Language doesn't specify timeouts for state machine definitions. Without an explicit timeout, Step Functions often relies solely on a response from an activity worker to know that a task is complete. If something goes wrong and the TimeoutSeconds field isn't specified for an Activity or Task state, an execution is stuck waiting for a response that will never come.

To avoid this situation, specify a reasonable timeout when you create a Task in your state machine"*

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. If you would like to post it as an answer, I will accept it as the answer. Also can I retry after a taks timeout? Can I retry the same task?